# SOQL multipicklist contains value

Tags: soql

I need to select a record from Salesforce and I have to use multi-picklist as a query condition.

the one of the value from multi-picklist equals to '**some test**'
I need somehow to select by the condition equals '**some**'
I mean:

```
SELECT FROM Account WHERE picklist INCLUDES ('some')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For picklists, you need to know the exact values you're looking for:

```
SELECT ... FROM Account WHERE SomeField INCLUDES ('some test')
```

You can't use a "like" operation with multi-select picklists.

Comment: Thanks, I know this but I believed that there exists some solution